# Error Loading CSS with Webpack and Babel

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, import, babeljs

I'm building a SSR React App with Webpack3 and Babel6 but when I run the server, it cannot find any css file (Error: Cannot find module './file.css').

Here is my folder structure so far:

```
src/
  |-components/
     |-App/
        |-App.css
        |-App.jsx
```

App.jsx

```
....
import './App.css';
....
```

webpack.config.js

```
....
module.exports: { loaders: [
  ....
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'], // I have loaders installed and included in package.json devDependencies
    include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    exclude: /node_modules/
  }
  ....
]}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Actually I've managed to load everything...but It's doing it "wrong". It's creating me a single css file and this is causing my imports crash... How can I solve this?

Comment: is your destination folder contains .css file along with your transpiled jsx file ?

Answer (score 0):

By default when you install packages locally, they go into node_modules folder in your project directory, therefore **style-loader** and **css-loader** are also included there. From your **webpack.config.js** file you are excluding this packages, which are needed in compiling your css assets. just remove the exclude line and every thing would be fine.

your **webpack.config.js** file would look like this.

```
webpack.config

....
module.exports: { loaders: [
....
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
}
....
]}
```